# Add multiple attributes in the Wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

What’s the correct syntax for using multiple attributes?

I'm using a plugin called Dropzone and it has multiple attribute options: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-dropzone/#faq

For example, if I want a different color background, I would include `[wp-dropzone background=”#fbfbfb”]`. But I also want to remove the links attribute `[wp-dropzone remove-links=”true”]`.

I can’t just put `remove-links=”true”` next to the color attribute or in the brackets: writing out both attributes fully gives me two dropzone boxes with the single attribute.

How would I write it out to get multiple attributes into a single "dropzone"?

Answer (score 2):

Several attributes in the wordpress exploding by space. Your shortcode will be:

```
[wp-dropzone background="#fbfbfb" remove-links="true"]
```

Comment: that removed the plugin and just displayed the text

Comment: not sure, that you're using right the shortcode. where do you placed it?

Comment: This answer should be correct. There must be something else wrong.